# Good reference book for OSX (non-obvious tips/tricks)

Tags: macos, mac

What are some good reference books for learning the subtleties of OSX? I found it fairly easy to pick up, but some things are kinda weird (like switching the default web browser, I had to get my friend who's a Mac expert to guide me through it).

Our library had 2 O'Reilly books on Mac OSX but a lot of the stuff mentioned in the books seemed like unnecessary fluff to me.

Answer (score 5):

While not a book, [Mac OS X Hints](http://www.macosxhints.com/) is a good place for tips and tricks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're looking for a user-level book, and there are already some good suggestions. But if you want the absolute hardcore low-level information, [Mac OS X Internals](http://osxbook.com/) is a must-read. It's not for the faint of heart, though.

Author Amit Singh writes:

> The book "Mac OS X Internals" describes the architecture and design of Apple's operating system. The book is targeted at anybody who is curious about Mac OS X and has a system-level interest in operating systems. At a very high (and simplistic) level, I expect this book to appeal to both those who use Mac OS X, and also those who do not.

Answer (score 2):

Is this one of the O'Reilly books you already know: [Mac OS X Hacks](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004606/)?

[image]

Judging from the title, publisher and description, it might be good stuff. (As a full disclosure, I haven't read it.)

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Mac OS X: The Missing Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059652952X) by David Pogue.

I also have a copy of the Mac OS X Hacks book that Jonik suggests and can recommend it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the books that Apple uses as part of it's certification program: [Apple Link](http://training.apple.com/selfpaced) . If you really want to know all the ins and outs these will give them to you.  Plus when your done you'll be super prepared to go take the certification tests.

For general OS X stuff I'd recommend the Support Essentials:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

MAX OS X for Unix geeks is a fab resource

Answer (score 0):

Don't miss Rui Carmo's fabulous guide on [How to Switch to the Mac](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/HOWTO/Switch%20To%20The%20Mac).